# Assembly language, program to check if a number is divideable by 2 and print numbers in a loop

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, numbers, comparison

I've a macro that's working, and getting big numbers in assembly language. I've been trying to make a program that'd print numbers divideable by 2. It seems to me that something's wrong with the comparison script I've written.

```
mov cx, number1 
check:
mov dx, cx
mov bx, 2
div bx
cmp ax, 0
je divide
add ax, 1

loop:
divide:
printNumber ax
add ax, 2
cmp ax, number2
je end
jmp loop
```

Comment: what do you think `div bx` does, and why do you think that?

Comment: it divides the registry of dx:ax by the value inside bx because the number takes 2 bytes. At least that's what I was taught

Comment: `div` puts the remainder in DX, not AX.  Also, on input, DX is the *high* half of the dividend, so you're doing `(cx << 16 + garbage_in_AX) / 2`.  Use a debugger to single-step if you want to see what actually happens.  The branching is a total mess, too, and doesn't look correct.  This is way overcomplicated; in binary you only need to check the low bit of CX with `test cl, 1`

Answer (score 4):

If the number for which you want to test if it's divisible by 2 is in *number1* and you know that the word division `div bx` actually divides `DX:AX` then you need to move the number to `AX` and zero `DX`.

```
check:
mov ax, number1 
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 2
div bx
```

The actual determination then comes from inspecting the **remainder** from this division by 2. The remainder is in the `DX` register!

```
cmp dx, 0
je  divisible
```

---

**But** all of this is overkill since testing to see if a number is even aka divisible by 2, is a simple matter of looking at its lowest bit:

```
test number1, 1
jz   divisible
```