# im writing a program to check if a number is divisble by 2 and 8 print numbers in loop and im having error parser instruction expected

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

Im writing a nasm program to check if a number is divisible by 2 and 8 and print numbers in loop and im having in the code at command 15 an error parser instruction expected how do i fix it. The error is at printNumber ax what is the solution and im using online compiler nasm. On visual studio i'm having error MSB8066 custom build exited with code 1

```
section .text
bits 64
global main
main :
mov cx, number1
check :
mov ax, number1
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 2
div bx
cmp dx, 0
je divisible
add ax, 1
loop:
divide:
printNumber, ax
add ax, 2
cmp ax, number2
je end
jmp loop
```

[The visual studio 2022 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHaFC.png)

Comment: `section.text` is already missing a space. `printNumber` is not an instruction, you likely forgot to include a macro package that has it defined.

Comment: Oh okay I fixed the section .text but the printNumber how do I fix it so that it doesnt give me an error cause I dont know how

Comment: Seems to be yet another version of [Assembly Language, program to check if a number is divisble by 2 and 8 and print numbers in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70380005). Except you changed `je divide` to `je divisible`, without changing the branch target, so you've introduced another reference to a symbol that doesn't exist.

Comment: Anyway, this was just a snippet in the original question [Assembly language, program to check if a number is divideable by 2 and print numbers in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50670234) not a complete program (not including a .data section containing `number1` or anything, or a print macro), so probably you're getting references to undefined symbols (even if you had a definition for a `printNumber` macro).  As the answer there points out, this code is horribly inefficient and isn't checking for divisibility by 8, no point trying to tweak it especially if you don't already understand it.

Comment: Also, "Custom build exited with code 1" isn't a meaningful error, it doesn't tell you anything about a problem or line number.  Is that some kind of overall summary, rather than error messages from the assembler specifically?  Surely VS can show you actual error messages; the codes should start with `A` for assembler error messages.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you help me write a nasm program that does that I would be really grateful if you help cause ive been trying for 2 weeks now and its not working

Comment: Or can you at least tell me how to fix this so it works im getting late to the deadline Im almost at it i still have few days

Comment: `global main` / `main:` / `xor eax,eax` / `mov edx, 1234` / `test dl, 7` / `setnz al` / `ret` will return 0 or 1 according to whether 1234 is divisible by 8 or not.  `mov eax, 1234` / `and eax, 1` / `ret`. will return 0 or 1 for even or odd.  If you assemble with NASM and link like you would a C compiler.  Like `nasm -felf64 foo.asm` / `gcc foo.o`.  Or I guess use `-fwin64` for Windows.

Comment: @PeterCordes is there a way to contact you on another platform like facebook or instagram or  by email or something i would be really grateful

Comment: We've seen this question 3 times in the last two days, so I suppose the whole class is confused.  I am too, why check if a number is divisible by 2 and 8?  Divisible by 8 means divisible by 2, so that's redundant.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Pretty sure it's the same person re-asking; notice the similarity in user-names.  They seem to be trying to start learning asm from scratch on SO, instead of finding a tutorial with a working Hello World and sticking different code into that.

Comment: @PeterCordes im still a university student and im still learning and this is my assignment and im asking here for help

Comment: Most university courses will introduce a set of tools, like an assembler and/or compiler for some OS, and show you a simple program in that.  So you can add new code inside that boilerplate.  But you seem to be casting around in the dark trying to build a whole program out of a snippet instead of using a snippet of code as part of your own program inside a template you were given.